# Página HTML no corpo do email com Video

Tags: html5, envio-de-email

Boa Tarde, minha empresa faz envios automaticos de uma pagina html dentro do corpo do email, foi me pedido que acrescentasse um vídeo dentro dessa página html. Até ai tudo bem, copiei o codigo que o youtube gera automatico como por exemplo esse abaixo:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7r1pqLDT-n8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

ao executar a pagina HTML, abre normalmente o vídeo, o problema é na hora que os envios são enviados essa tag  é ignorada, que metodo eu poderia utilizar para que renderizasse um video dentro do email e não fosse enviado para o SPAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O uso de `<iframe>` dentro do email é totalmente desencorajado. Por rasões de segurança a maioria dos clientes de email bloqueiam essa tag, ou na pior das hipóteses coloca seu email em um *black-list* e marcado como spam.

O problema é que existem vários métodos de ataque que comprometem a segurança quando se permite um `<iframe>`. Os iframes geralmente contêm scripts, portanto, a maioria dos clientes de email os bloqueia.

Aqui tem uma lista do que não se deve usar no corpo do email

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E uma lista não muito atual dos clientes de email que aceitam `iframs`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Portanto a recomendação é que não os use.**

---

### Alternativas

Essas são algumas dicas que podem abrir sua cabeça para outras opções.

- Botões de apelo à ação para clicar no vídeo
- Hiperlinks de texto com o link de vídeo
- Imagens e gráficos que podem ser clicados e levar pro vídeo

Aqui um exemplo que pode facilmente levar seu *prospect* a abrir seu vídeo, basta vc colocar uma imagem do vídeo dentro do email com o link do vídeo no Youtube.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<a href="https://youtube.com" target="_blank" title="Ver no youtube">
  <img src="http://s2.glbimg.com/atodMXRwpeKZYXkb-pt3J28myOc=/0x0:695x440/695x440/s.glbimg.com/po/tt2/f/original/2016/04/19/telaverdenoyoutube.jpg" alt="Clique para ver o vídeo">
</a>
```